# How to Checked MenuItem independently

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form application which has a menutrip on it . In my application a menu has some menuitem in it , and one of them in default menu .

My user should be able to change default menu . So i use checked property for it . 
Every things is alright but i want to change default menu if **ONLY** click on checked area , and when click on checked area does not fire click event .

I created a class which inherited from MenuItem for some stuff . I think if i can capture click event and get position of cursor and finally check point of click is in bounds of checked area  i could handle my problem . But in menu item i have a limited access to do this .

any suggestion will be appreciate .

**Edit** : unfortunately in OnClick method can not get location of control , bounds of paint text and checked and so on . I use Cursor.Position to determine point of click and declare a variable to hole bounds of MenuItem which fill on OnDrawItem . And also with blow code i know the rectange of checked mark :

```
 sidebarRect = new Rectangle(bounds.X + bounds.Width - SidebarSize, bounds.Y, SidebarSize, bounds.Height);
```

**Edit2** : Let me explain more . I want to have somthing line a label and checkbox in menuItem . If it happens , User can checked and checked checkbox independently with out selecting the whole menuitem . But checked propery of menu item changes with selecting menuitem . Imagine a menu with 5 menuItem with a radio or checked box and you can change the radio/check to set the default menuitem .

Comment: Please show the code instead of describing it.

Comment: Actually i don't have code to show . I want to find path to solve the problem

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem but looks like it's a strange behavior, hovering and clicking on the *checked area* should bring some special effect to notify the user about some **function**, you don't even care about that?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like a combobox dropdown item.  Click on an item and it changes the text in the combobox.  It has several events that can be handled when an item is changed that you can pass to whatever subroutine or object you need.

Comment: No , I want a Context menu which has some items and user can checked each item without context menu hide . When user click in text or somewhere which not check mark , hide .